# Check if user likes Facebook page from website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This might be a bit of a silly question to ask but I'm just wondering if it's possible to check if a user likes your Facebook page on a website by using Facebook's API without creating an app.

It seems weird to have an app, popup permissions and all that to simply check if a user likes a Facebook page or not.

The idea is to hide some content if the user is not a fan of the Facebook page. Does this stil l require creating an app?

Answer (score 0):

Without using Graph API- **No**

If you don't use the Graph API how would you even you who is logged-in via facebook. You cant even get the currently-logged-in user without Graph API.

I'm not sure if you need this, but to get this thing done using the Graph API, here's what you have to do-

- ask for the permission `user_likes` from the user and login
- call the API- `/me/likes/PAGE_ID`

If you get some response that means the user had liked the page already, else if you get the blank data that means user has not liked this page yet.